# Equation with powers of complex variables and its conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do you solve an equation like this?  $(3z)^2 + (4\bar{z})^4 = 0 $

I tried setting the complex variable to its polar form $re^{i\theta}$ and simplifying but ended up with $re^{-i3\theta} = \pm\frac{3i}{16}$. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: So you have $r\cos(3\theta)=0$ and $r\sin(3\theta)=\mp\dfrac 3{16}$. Can you solve these equations simultaneously for $r,\theta$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar form,

$$9r^2e^{i2\theta}=-256r^4e^{-i4\theta}.$$

Taking the moduli, $9r^2=256r^4$.

Taking the arguments, $2\theta=(2k+1)\pi-4\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $z^2=x+iy$

$$0=9(x+iy)+256(x-iy)^2=9x+256(x^2-y^2)+i(9y-256\cdot2xy)=0$$

Now equate the real & the imaginary parts.

Comment: Little typo: $(x-iy)^2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Agreed

Answer (score 0):

If $z=re^{it}$

$$9r^2e^{2it}+256r^4e^{-4it}=0$$

$$r^2e^{-4it}(9e^{6it}+256r^2)=0$$

As $|e^{in}|=1,e^{in}\ne0,$

So, either  $r^2=0\iff r=0$

or $9e^{6it}+256r^2=0\iff256r^2=-9e^{6it}$

Taking modulus in both sides $256r^2=9\iff r=\dfrac3{16}$ as $r>0$

$\implies e^{6it}=-\dfrac{256r^2}9=?=e^{i\pi}$

$\implies6it=(2m+1)\pi i$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

$z=0$ is an obvious solution. Then multiply by $z^4$, giving

$$3^2z^6+4^4|z^4|=0$$
so that $z^6$ is a negative real and $z$ is proportional to a *sixth root of $-1$*, let $z=\lambda\sqrt[6]{-1}$.

Then $-3^2\lambda^6+4^4\lambda^4=0$ gives

$$z=\frac3{16}\sqrt[6]{-1}.$$